# Font used in scientific articles diagrams/graphs

Tags: publications, graphics

I'm very careful with visual appearance of what I write, and I want to know if there is some convention with the font used in the graphs or diagrams of an article. Normally the articles are written with the defoult LaTex font,

- LaTex font, `Tex`

[image]

But in the other hand there are a lot of articles in internet that for the graphics use the default font of python matplotlib, that I  have seen a lot in sites as [SciPost](https://scipost.org/) for example,

- Python font `sans-serif`

[image]

Wich one do you think is better or more appropiate for an article?, or if exist some convention that tells the graphics should be in the same font that the article.

What you do in your articles?

Comment: The "TeX font" is called Computer Modern.

Answer (score 11):

I will cite from a contribution by Jillian M. Buriak (see reference below):

> Sans serif fonts are ideal for graphics because they have a cleaner appearance, enabling your reader to quickly read the text unimpeded as they work through your data. Many people have a strong aversion to Times font in graphics, particularly in chemical structures (e.g., ChemDraw images), and thus a standard Arial or Helvetica font will avoid such an effect.

This is pretty much in line with what I think is aesthetic, but surely it is partly a matter of personal preference. And, as usual, when preparing graphics for publication in a journal, consult the corresponding author guidelines. Often, journals have specific requirements for formatting.

---

**Reference:**

Jillian M. Buriak, "Which Font Looks Best in a Figure?", *Chem. Mater.* **2016**, *28*, 3, 689–690. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.chemmater.6b00306

Answer (score 10):

The best font for scientific diagrams and graphs is the **same font** or fonts that are used in the main text of the paper itself. This consistency is particularly important for mathematics, where the way how each symbol appears may significantly impact what this particular symbol means.

The way to achieve is for example to embed graphs as pdf+LaTeX or TikZ in your main TeX-based document. Alternatively, you may need to set up your graph-drawing software with the fonts used in the style file of your target journal, which may not be easy to find and also may be subject to change.

Comment: *The way to achieve is for example to embed graphs as pdf+LaTeX or TikZ in your main TeX-based document.* – This needs an restriction like: “if the journal accepts this”. Even in the TeX-friendly field of physics, most journals don’t accept embedded TeX files as graphics.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft From my experience, the chance to have it accepted is higher if you never ask.

Comment: True, but so is the chance to waste your time. Also, IIRC, at least some journals explicitly disallow this.

Comment: I do not disagree, but generally I think the more we push for the right things, the more chances journals are to accommodate it. And embedded graphics (like TikZ) is clearly a right thing compared to external pdf or even jpg.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part the choice of font is a matter of taste (on which I am mostly neutral).

There is one exception: When possible mathematical symbols should appear in the same font as they appear in the main text. For mathematical symbols, different typesetting is often used to convey different meanings. Consequently, even when your text does not ascribe a different meaning to x in a serif font vs x in a sans-serif font, having a different symbol appear in your graphics can lead to unnecessary confusion among your readers.

(This effect is amplified for the typesetting of non-latin characters.)